# java.lang.StackOverflowError with Spring Boot Actuator & Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application with spring-boot-starter-actuator enabled.
If I deploy the war file into a tomcat container, I get a stack overflow when I hit unmapped uri.

```
2014-06-03 17:24:28,312 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-3]             o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/catalog/products] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
    Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-3" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.setErrorAttributes(ErrorPageFilter.java:164)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:104)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:135)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:104)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
```

I tried implementing the ErrorController, but it did not work. Did anyone see similar issue? What could be causing this?

But if I run using the embedded tomcat server, everything looks good with the white label error page displayed. For various operational reasons, I need to run the app inside a tomcat container. Any help is highly appreciated.

**Update:**
I narrowed it down to a filter that wraps servlet request & response. I am at a loss to explain why it has issues when both this filter and actuator are included in a tomcat container. It works fine when either one of them is not included. I have created a sample app with just enough code to replicate it here in a [Sample Code](https://github.com/vgadang/spring-actuator-stack-overflow)

Comment: I think this is the first question about StackOverflows I've seen on StackOverflow... ;)

Comment: Check [issue #694](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/694)

Comment: Are you saying this is the result of your having implemented the `ErrorController`? A vanilla webapp deployed to Tomcat works fine for me, so maybe you need to share a project?

Comment: I finally narrowed it down to a filter that wraps servlet request & response. I am at a loss to explain why it has issues when both this filter and actuator are included in a tomcat container. It works fine when either one of them is not included. I have created a sample app with just enough code to replicate it [here](https://github.com/vgadang/spring-actuator-stack-overflow)

Comment: I had similar behavior. I removed actuator from my project after reading your updated, and the issue stopped as well. That was a nice-to-have for me, so I'm happy to drop it if it means I don't have to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug with Spring Boot 1.1.4. Check out https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1343. Fixed in version 1.1.5.

Comment: It appears to be fixed in the newer versions of spring boot.